# table spacing when displaying uncertainties

Tags: tables, spacing

I am trying to present the results of my data with +/- uncertainties. However the table I have created doesn't fit around the data very well, and I cannot figure out how to alter my code to make the table deeper.

Comment: Can you show us? Pretty please?

Comment: To echo and expand on @Werner's comment, it's best if you give the exact code of your table and data, so that we can compile it and try to find a better solution. Also, what do you mean by "very well" and "deeper?" Would you like more or less spacing in a particular direction? How would you like to expand your table (the assumed meaning of "deeper")? If you answer these questions, we'll be much better placed to help you solve your problem.